# Gradient bounds on a solution of a linear elliptic problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Take $\Omega$ to be a bounded domain in $N$ dimensional Euclidean space with smooth boundary and we assume $\Omega$ contains the origin.     I am interested is the following equation

$$ \Delta \phi(x) +  \gamma \sum_{i,j=1}^N  \frac{x_i x_j}{|x|^2} \phi_{x_i x_j}(x) = f(x)$$ in $\Omega$ with $ \phi=0$ on $ \partial \Omega$.    Here $\gamma$ is such that the operator is elliptic.     I would like to get some estimate of the form
$$ \sup_{\Omega}| \nabla \phi(x)| \le C \sup_\Omega |f(x)|.$$   I guess there might be some issues at the origin.  I have tried cutting the domain off and trying to get estimates independent of the domain cut off;  but I was not successful.        I guess part of my problem is that I don't truly understand the estimates I use;  but normally I can perturb off the Lapclian and not really need to understand the main ideas.

**QUESTION**.   Is this gradient estimate true and are there any standard methods to try and prove this fact?
The method I tried was the $C^{1,\alpha}$ blow up analysis method from Leon Simon;  but I couldn't get it to work.

thanks

Comment: The operator in this problem is not in divergence form.  This is  not typical in problems that have geometric or physical significance.    I have two suggestions. 1. Write the operator in polar/spherical coordinates.  2.Look at this paper of Stampacchia  http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=SJL_1963-1964___3_1_0  It is about operators with discontinuous coefficients  in divergence form  and your operator is really close to one. Maybe you can glean some ideas in this paper.

Comment: Everything should be contained in the last section of "Elliptic and parabolic problems for a class of operators with discontinuous coefficients", Annali SNS vol XiX (2019), by L. Negro, C. Spina and myself. We deal mainly with the whole space and and $W^{2,p}$ regularity but when some $p>N$ is allowed, then the gradient estimate follow from Sobolev embeddding.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments.  I will look through both mentioned references.      If someone wants to make their comment an answer I can accept it.  In anycase thank you for your very useful comments;  its is much appreciated

Comment: @Giorgio.  Is there access to this paper online somewhere? I searched a bit and can't seem to get access.  Thanks

Comment: If you give me an email I can send to you in the afternoon. Please write to giorgio.metafune@unisalento.it